# processing sketch integration with live wallpaper in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, live, processing, wallpaper

Is it possible to integrate the Processing sketch as part of the android live wallpaper instead of OpenGL ? I would like to have interaction with different objects in wallpaper so processing would be easy for me as an artist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, no.

See this discussion on the Processing Forum.

https://forum.processing.org/topic/android-live-wallpaper

Comment: I'm not sure... but AFAIK, there is no way to use the Processing library from the Processing IDE to do this, as the compiler written by Processing is strictly tied to the Activity class, which is tied to the activity lifecycle of presenting content onscreen as a runtime application. It *IS* possible to use Processing as a library from within Eclipse ((not sure about Android Studio) there are a few tutorials about this on their Wiki), so if you find a template for a live wallpaper, you could conceivably use Processing as your graphics renderer for that...

Comment: Ok, yeah, I did get a simple live wallpaper app working and it's essentially the same as drawing in an HTML5 canvas. I think it would be pretty easy to use the processing library inside that demo to wrap the drawing functions.

Comment: @chrisallick where can we find the source for that demo? The above forum post is 404 :(

Comment: @GregMiernicki it was a quick sprint and now archived on a hard drive somewhere. I've given up on Android dev. The dev environment is too garbage on mac. Here is a link to a tutorial that will get you pretty far though http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Version 4 of the Processing editor's Android mode includes live wallpaper functionality. It's still in beta, but it's the best I found so far. You can download it from here: https://github.com/processing/processing-android/releases.

From http://android.processing.org/install.html:

> The 4.0 pre-releases bring several improvements to the Android mode, incuding new functionality for creating live wallpapers, watch faces, and Cardboard apps. You will find more on how to use this functionality in the tutorials and the reference pages of this site. In order to install a 4.0 pre-release manually, go to the GitHub releases section, look for the packages corresponding to Android Mode 0254 (4.0-beta1) or higher, and follow the instructions in the previous paragraph on how to install a pre-release.